# Is there a SQL Server Profiler for SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql-server, profiling, sql-server-express

Is there a SQL Server Profiler for SQL Server Expess? Maybe an open-source one? Or maybe just a tool that helps me see what query is passed to the database?

Comment: Now is thread closed, but one another link to working piece of software is here: https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/

Comment: You can use MS SQL Profiler against SQL Express, so download an evaluation version of SQL Server full edition or buy the $50 SQL Server Developer Edition. Otherwise you can use the `sp_trace_*` procedures directly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187346.aspx

Comment: See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28213/download-sql-server-profiler-for-sql-server-management-studio

Answer (score 18):

SP1 of SQL Server Express 2012 Advanced Services now includes the full SQL Management Studio, and this has the profiler.

Comment: It can be downloaded here 
`Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Service Pack 1 (SP1) Express` https://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35579

Answer (score 13):

Ok, old question but maybe this helps other people with same problem.

You can activate the SQL Server Express Error Log in a way that it monitors all statements runned agaist every database. To do so you must run the following on an elevated command prompt (that is, a command prompt runned as administrator):

```
net stop MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
net start MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS /T4032
```

Now, using the SQL Server Management Studio run the following:

```
dbcc traceon(3605, -1)
```

Now you can look at the ERRORLOG file within the Log folder of MS SQL folder (which may be "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log" for the default installation of SQL Server Express 2012).

Hope this helps someone (as it sure helped me)

Comment: This works very good.. thanks man

Answer (score 5):

IIRC, the profiler is one of the features not available for SQL Server Express.

However, I'm also under the impression that SQL Server Express still supports *many* of the features of the for-pay editions, and it's just that they are disabled in the Express Edition of Management Studio.  So if you also have access to a full db and the management studio that comes with you *might* be able to point that profiler at your express installation.

In this case I suspect that won't work, since the profiler also depends on an extra provided by the database.  Still, it's worth a shot.

If it doesn't work there are some third party tools available that should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Yes - this works; you can even use the eval edition for a period of time. http://blog.tonysneed.com/2010/08/05/setting-up-sql-server-2008-express-with-profiler/

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Express Profiler](http://www.DataWizard.com/) will likely meet your needs. When this question was asked it was free, but it looks like it has recently changed to a paid license model.

Comment: This people are selling it for $5

Answer (score 1):

Anjlab SQL Server Profiler is no longer free and it only worked on 2005 instances. I've wrote a basic SQL Server 2012 Profiler which works perfectly on 2012 Enterprise and 2005 Developer engine instances. You can [download here](http://ivanz.webuda.com/)

please give me your feedback.