# MVC4 + SQL Server Express gives yellow screen with "login failed for user.." using known good credentials

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have been tasked with deploying an application that has been successfully running in a development environment to a staging environment. After deploying the published files and configuring IIS, I can see the inital login screen, as expected. However, when I try and log in, I get:

```
Cannot open database "db1" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'user1'.
```

The setup contains these pieces: 
Windows Web Server 2008 R2,
SQL Server Express 2008 R2,
IIS 7,
ASP.NET MVC4, and
Entity Framework 4.4

Googling turned up no sucessful leads - answers posted here and elsewhere were all concerned with either the credentials ultimately being incorrect or dual-mode authentication not being enabled in server properties. 
I see dual-mode authentication enabled in server properties, and I can confirm this by logging in with either SQL Server or Windows authentication in SSMS. This also confirms to me that the credentials are good and accepted by the server. (Please correct me if I'm wrong in thinking this)

SQL Server, IIS, and the browser I'm testing with are all running on the same machine.

Here is my connection string: (with internal info substituted out)

```
<add name="app1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/app1.csdl|res://*/app1.ssdl|res://*/app1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=db1;user id=user1;password=pass1;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: I copied your connection string and tried in my app it haven't been working (other errors though) but try to change attribute providerName of <add> to System.Data.SqlClient. It's at the end of the line.

Comment: @Sebastian.Belczyk Thanks for the reply. I tried the change you suggested, I now get a yellow screen saying: "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'". I would guess the SqlClient doesn't like EF's nasty extras in the connection string.

Comment: I removed metadata part to test it in code first configuration and I got same exception but it was complaining about 'data source' it was fine when changed this attribute, so we're back in the square one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the resolution. It was ultimately a permissions issue. 
This question got me on the right track: 
[SQL Server: Cannot open database requested by the login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622604/sql-server-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login)

Examining the server logs showed:
"Failed to open the explicitly specified database", then
"Error 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38"

Google revealed that state 38 means a permissions problem. This particular user had the 'public' server permission and the 'db_datareader' and 'db_datawriter' permissions on the database already so I deleted and remade the user on the database, which fixed the issue.

EDIT:

This was happening to me every time I restored the database. Apparently SQL server gets confused about users on restore. The fix is to execute this:

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login UPDATE_ONE, 'username_of_user', 'username_of_user';
```

After a restore, which fixes the issue entirely.