# Failed to create database Entity Framework code-first

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create a database using Entity Framework with a **code-first** approach, but it fails on creating the database with this exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.DataException:
>   An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "X.Xcontext" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'This-PC\ME'.

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: As per exception, I think that SQL has not enabled for windows login  or your connection string is not properly build with integrated security. Kindly cross check both scenario.

Comment: It looks like the user This-PC\ME doesn't have permissions to this database called X.Xcontext.  You'll have to set up this user with permissions before they can create tables and so forth.

Comment: @criticalfix How can I set up user with permissions in VS ?

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio.  You may need a database administrator to do this part if you're not familiar with SSMS, or if you don't have access on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot open database "test" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'xyz\ASPNET'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575907/cannot-open-database-test-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-fail)

Comment: @SteveGreene No it isn't! It's addressing the problem in Database first approach not code first as mine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Problem solved when I just renamed my DbContext..Don't know why,but it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Your user does not have permissions to create a database, you will need to contact your DBA for permissions, or depending on where you work you'll need to create a ticket to have someone create the database for you.

Comment: I'm working on my local machine, how can I change users permissions ?

Comment: Try this https://esha.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202977089-Granting-Access-to-Additional-Users-with-SQL-Server-Management-Studio