# Fail to open the database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Well, i know this question was asked many times on this platform. Nothing seems to work for me. I looked at this [Cannot open database "test" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'xyz\ASPNET'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575907/cannot-open-database-test-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-fail). I fully understand that.

The case is the database was created by default when i created the application. I choose the Individual Authentication. I then expand the database using the Entity Framework 6. I want to create a CRUD operation through the Entity Framework 6 by generating .edmx file. The error occurs when I tried to attach the database to the program.

I tried opening it with MSSQL Server to assign right to the user. After it will complain the file is corrupt. If anyone will help me to open it or how to generate a CRUD on that. I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see your connection string something like below

`Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=something;Integrated Security=True`

Remove `Integrated Security=True` from your connection string then it will work

**Update**

it is recommended to keep `Integrated Security` . When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.Possible states are `true`, `false`, `yes`, `no`, and `sspi` [Read More](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)