# How to see LINQ generated SQL in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition?

Tags: linq-to-entities

can someone explain me how to check LINQ generated SQL queries in VWD 2008?

I just have not enough time for figuring it out by myself, so any help is appreciated

Thanks

EDIT:
I am using SQL Server 2008, Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL Server Profiler (free with SQL Server, which you say you already have) or LINQPad.

Answer (score 1):

You could buy Linq to Sql profiler.

It's pretty steep (imo) but looks like a great tool if you can afford it or justify the costs.

There are free ways to do what you ask but I cant remember off the top of my head.

I am assuming you are also using SQL Server Express. Check this thread out. 
[Is there a SQL Server Profiler for SQL Server Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760321/is-there-a-sql-server-profiler-for-sql-express)

Addendum, just noticed you are actually using Linq to Entities. The same guy sells this for that framework.

http://efprof.com/

Sorry for the rather vague options but I hope they help. You orginally said you was pressed for time (before editing) so i helped you do the groundwork for some reasearch.

Comment: Thank you for the options, but i really can't go with buying something, as i am on summer practice, and i'll be gone from this place in less than two months :)